# Community Visualization | Violates Content Security Policy Directive img-src https://datastudio.google.com

Tags: javascript, looker-studio

I created a community visualization in Data Studio to add a single image as a test.

Here is the code

```
my_first_image = document.createElement('img');
my_first_image.setAttribute('src', 'https://anyimageurl.com/hi.jpg' );
document.body.appendChild(my_first_image);
```

This code generates the following error:
Refused to load the image 'https://anyimageurl.com/hi.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src https://datastudio.google.com/".

I have tried to set the meta tag in DataStudio with the following code:

```
  var meta = document.createElement('meta');
  meta.httpEquiv = "Content-Security-Policy";
  meta.content = "img-src *;script-src *";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
  console.log(h);
```

I have tried changing meta.content tag to all possible settings from https://content-security-policy.com/, none of which have resulted in any different results.

I'm expecting for the image to show in my community visualization and instead i get an error

Comment: I've run into this as well. Tables in GDS pull images through a proxy, so my guess is that this is by design which is super unfortunate.

Comment: I created a calculated field using IMAGE in DataStudio and extracted the proxy URL, and still the image does not load either when i set the .src attribute to the proxy URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External requests do not currently work in Community Visualizations because of the [Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/issues), so loading images in Data Studio Community Visualizations will also not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe someone will get here & see my answer.

The workaround is:

1. Create an SVG image
2. Paste it via CSS like this

```
.image-box {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%"><image x="0" y="0" width="100%" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" /></svg>');
}
```